# Haskell - 2D List of Ints to String

Tags: string, list, haskell, int

I'm looking to convert a 2D list to a formatted string.

```
table :: [[Int]] -> String

Input: [[11,2,30],[4,555,9]]

Output: " 11   2 30 \n  4 555   6 \n"

        11   2  30
         4 555   9
```

Basically would need to be able to print out in a grid-shape and maintain formatting to account for the max value.

I know for simple lists I can map show `[1,2,3,4] -> ["1","2","3","4"]` according to ghci. That seems to keep it as a list though?

Not sure how I can traverse the 2D and keep concatenating as a string and adding `\n` as needed.

Comment: Hi Eli, it'd be more helpful if you could show us an example of what you've tried so far, and what the current output is vs the expected output (or any errors you might be running into).

Comment: `words` and `lines` might be helpful functions in your attempt. As regards lining the columns up, you'll could try taking the `maximum` of `length` across the strings and `replicate` prefaced `' '` characters to make the widths equal.

Comment: Do you know what algorithm you'd use and are having trouble implementing or are you having trouble figuring out even algorithmically what to do?  If you are looking for a pre-packaged pretty printing solution suggestion then that is explicitly off topic, but people on reddit will likely be quite helpful.

Comment: @ThomasM.DuBuisson I'm having trouble figuring out what to even do. So far I've managed to go through the 2D List and turn them all internal integer elements into Strings but what I want is to grab the elements and form them into a single String.

Comment: Turning them into  _a_ string is easy.  You can `concat` the whole list of strings.  However, you want to pad out each value with spaces to make each column a matching length.  Can you work through the algorithm that would achieve this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Playing at the REPL can help.

```
> :t '1'
'1' :: Char

> :t "1"
"1" :: [Char]

> ['1','2']
"12" :: [Char]

> :t concat
concat :: [[a]] -> [a]

> concat ( map show [1,2,3,4] )
.....

> concat [ show x | x <- [1,2,3,4] ]
.....

> concat [ " " ++ ( ensureWidth 9 (show x) ) | x <- [1,2,3,4] ]
.....

> :t replicate
replicate :: Int -> a -> [a]

> replicate 2 '1'
"11" :: [Char]
```

Now you need to write the function

```
ensureWidth w s = replicate n ' ' ++ s
```

but what `n` to use? You will need to know the length of `s`, for that. Function [`length`](https://hoogle.haskell.org/?hoogle=length) can help.

Comment: In the example the width needed depends on the maximum length item in the column, so it would be a `maximum . map length <$> transpose` style operation.

Comment: @ThomasM.DuBuisson yes, that would be the logical next step, for the OP to ask themself, "why the width of 10?". :)